# Using Page Render Vs ResponseFilters

Tags: asp.net

Basically i am looking at a way of removing script tags for a given page.I have done this using a RegEx to do this "src=\"({0})\"."  in  override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) method.But i have found that the the Time for the First Byte increases if the HTML is manipulated in the Render Method.I am wondering if there is a better way to do this using ResponseFilters without a compromise on the performance

```
                StringBuilder regExpressionForScriptTags = new StringBuilder();
                regExpressionForScriptTags.AppendFormat("<script .*src=\"({0})\".*</script>", sRepalcableScripts);

                Regex scriptTags = new Regex(regExpressionForScriptTags.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                MatchCollection collection = scriptTags.Matches(RawHtml);

                int? firstMatchPosition = null;

                RawHtml = scriptTags.Replace(RawHtml, new MatchEvaluator(delegate(Match match)
                {
                    if (!firstMatchPosition.HasValue)
                        firstMatchPosition = match.Index;

                    return string.Empty;
                }));
```

Comment: If you are searching through all your output, it is going to hit somewhere. Just out of curiosity, why are you getting rid of the script tags? They are there for a reason.

Comment: removing all script tags which need to be consolidated into a single JS file

Comment: Rather than taking the runtime hit everytime, why not do it statically?